# Setting replyTo to a TMP Queue

Tags: jms, wso2-esb

Doing only JMS based messaging through the ESB.  ESB has a dedicated REQUEST queue where clients send service requests with a SOAP wrapper.  Wrapper gets interpreted for service name and version, registry lookup, routes to service QUEUE.  Service responds to ESB on dedicated ESB REPLY queue.  Need to then correlate to correct stored request to send reply back to client on it's TMP queue.  I have no idea how to save the original JMS request's TMP queue to some kind of cache using the service Sent Msg ID as key so I can retrieve original requests message ID and TMP QUEUE?

So two questions.  How to access the jms msg headers in the proxy config.  How to set some kind of cache or store with data to be used on responses to correlate them back to requests and set replies.  No pure JMS samples at all in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this more or less the flow ?

```
CLIENT --> request-queue --> ESB --> service-queue --> SERVICE
then
SERVICE --> response-queue --> ESB --> tmp-queue --> CLIENT
```

I propose:

1. Client calls [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html).[createTemporaryQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTemporaryQueue%28%29). The temporary queue returned can be re-used while the same connection is in use, so this would be a once per connection operation.
2. Client sends request, adding the temporary queue as the reply destination by calling [Message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html).[setJMSReplyTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo%28javax.jms.Destination%29)(tempTopic).
3. ESB receives the request, does its registry thing and forwards the request to the SERVICE, again setting the JMSReplyTo on the message to the client's temporary queue.
4. The SERVICE does its thing and sends the response directly to the destination in the messages JMSReplyToHeader.  (Any specific reason why the response has to go back through the ESB ?)

So the flow would actually be:

```
CLIENT --> request-queue --> ESB --> service-queue --> SERVICE
then
SERVICE --> tmp-queue --> CLIENT
```

There's 2 gotchas I can think of right off the bat (and pressed, I'm sure I could come up with more....)

- The SERVICE is operating on a different broker and cannot send directly to the client's temporary queue.

In this case, have the ESB maintain a cache of client temp-queues keyed by the message-id. When the ESB sends its request to the service, set the JMSCorrelationId header to the message-id of the message received from the CLIENT. The SERVICE should read the JMSCorrelationId from the message it receives, and also add it to the response message it sends back to the ESB.  (confused yet ?) Now the ESB receives a response from SERVICE, unpacks the JMSCorrelationId, looks up the corresponding temp-queue and sends the response on it.

Rather than caching the temp-queue by messageId, if your CLIENT can always supply a unique client-id, you could cache the temp-queue by that instead (less granular). The your contract with the SERVICE switches from JMSCorrelationId to the client-id. In my experience, though, it is considered the-polite-thing-to-do for a request-response JMS service to always return the proivided correlationId, where as arbitrary headers.... not so much.

Comment: The service cannot be configured to reply to the client's TMP queue both for the reasons you state and that would require the reconfiguration of thousands of services....so all service responses must go back into the ESB on the ESB defined reply queue and then be correlated back to the correct client on that client's TMP queue.

Comment: This was a snap with UltraESB, but just can't put 2 and 2 together on wxo2.  With Ultra they have a nifty cache API where I use the sent message ID (the ID of the message going to the service) as the key and a String array with the client's original messageID and ReplyTo as the value object.  When I get a service reply back, I grab it's original ID, do a cache lookup, extract the cache entry, put the client message ID back onto the JMS transport header and send it to the replyTo value (the original client TMP reply queue).  Works like a champ there, so need a matching wso2 mechanism

Comment: Sounds like UltraESB created something specifically designed to handle this issue ? Well, in the absence of anything else, you could always create your own simple cache. I would recommend a singleton with support for either soft/weak references or time based expiration (no sense keeping all that stuff around long after it has become non-useful...) My goto these days for this sort of thing is Google Guava Cache: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: Ultra's global cache facility is a base part of the product, but yea, probably created specifically for this kind of use case. Thanks, doing my own cache seems like the right approach.  Was hoping wso2 had a global cache facility I could use and was just missing something, but guess not.  Surprised someone else hasn't had this issue before, didn't think we were that unique...

Comment: Digging in a bit more, appears like I need to write a custom axis2 module that performs the caching I need.